# Network Analysis: Polygon service areas

Tags: gis, arcgis, arcmap, network-analysis

I'm trying to run a network analysis and was wondering if there was a way to have the service area facilities as polygons instead of points?

I've tried the feature to point tool but this create one point which doesn't account for the whole area of the polygon.

Is there a tool that creates multiple points that outline the polygon?

Comment: This looks like a question far more on-topic at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange than here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer the first paragraph (I am not sure I fully understand connection with the second part).

Besides buffers, readily available in ArcMap, with an ArcGIS Desktop extension one can crate Drive Time polygons around point features:

1. With `Business Analyst` extension, Drive Time polygons can be created using the eponymous tool:

   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/business-analyst-toolbox/drive-time.htm

   As they state,

   > You can create more advanced drive-time polygons with custom road
   >   networks, adding barriers, and the like with the ArcGIS Network
   >   Analyst tools
2. With `Network Analyst` extension, `Make Service Area Layer` tool is available:

   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/make-service-area-layer.htm

   > After creating the analysis layer with this tool, you can add network
   >   analysis objects to it using the Add Locations tool, solve the
   >   analysis using the Solve tool, and save the results on disk using the
   >   Save To Layer File tool.
3. With `Network Analyst` extension, `Generate Service Areas` could be used for setting up a service areas Geoprocessing service:

   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/generate-service-areas.htm

   > Creates a service area network analysis layer, sets the analysis
   >   properties, and solves the analysis. This tool is ideal for setting up
   >   a service area geoprocessing service on the web. A network service
   >   area is a region that encompasses all streets that can be accessed
   >   within a given distance or travel time from one or more facilities.

   Example:

   http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/gp-service-example-drivetime-polygons.htm
4. With an `an ArcGIS Online for organizations account`, one can consume a ready to go service:

   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/itemdesc-generate-service-areas.htm

   > It is a service that runs like a geoprocessing tool within ArcMap, can
   >   be accessed from other applications, and includes high-quality road
   >   data for much of the world.

UPDATE:
From ArcGIS Online Help (see the Examples section):

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/create-drive-time-areas.htm